# React Native Component will receive is deprecated

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a new react native app after writing some code I got this warning :

[image]

in the emulator.

But I don't see where the problem is.

This is my code - App.js:

```
const IS_ANDROID = Platform.OS === 'android';
const SLIDER_1_FIRST_ITEM = 1;

class App extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        slider1ActiveSlide: SLIDER_1_FIRST_ITEM
    };
}

  _renderItem ({item, index}) {
    return <SliderEntry data={item} even={(index + 1) % 2 === 0} />;
}

_renderItemWithParallax ({item, index}, parallaxProps) {
    return (
        <SliderEntry
          data={item}
          even={(index + 1) % 2 === 0}
          parallax={true}
          parallaxProps={parallaxProps}
        />
    );
}

_renderLightItem ({item, index}) {
    return <SliderEntry data={item} even={false} />;
}

_renderDarkItem ({item, index}) {
    return <SliderEntry data={item} even={true} />;
}

mainExample (number, title) {
  const { slider1ActiveSlide } = this.state;

  return (
      <View style={styles.exampleContainer}>
          <Carousel
            ref={c => this._slider1Ref = c}
            data={ENTRIES1}
            renderItem={this._renderItemWithParallax}
            sliderWidth={sliderWidth}
            itemWidth={itemWidth}
            hasParallaxImages={true}
            firstItem={SLIDER_1_FIRST_ITEM}
            inactiveSlideScale={0.94}
            inactiveSlideOpacity={0.7}
            // inactiveSlideShift={20}
            containerCustomStyle={styles.slider}
            contentContainerCustomStyle={styles.sliderContentContainer}
            loop={true}
            loopClonesPerSide={2}
            autoplay={true}
            autoplayDelay={4000}
            autoplayInterval={3000}
            onSnapToItem={(index) => this.setState({ slider1ActiveSlide: index }) }
          />
      </View>
  );
}

get gradient () {
  return (
      <LinearGradient
        colors={[colors.background1, colors.background2]}
        startPoint={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
        endPoint={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
        style={styles.gradient}
      />
  );
}
render () {
  const example1 = this.mainExample(1);

  return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <StatusBar
                translucent={true}
                backgroundColor={'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'}
                barStyle={'light-content'}
              />
              { this.gradient }
              <ScrollView
                style={styles.scrollview}
                scrollEventThrottle={200}
                directionalLockEnabled={true}
              >
                  { example1 }
              </ScrollView>
          </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
}
```

export default App;

All I used is this carousel library https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel nothing else but I don't know what I am doing wrong in this case
and is it really the code isn't going to work in the future ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by the warning, `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated.

The component `react-native-snap-carousel` use that feature and is deprecated in the latest version of react-native.

You have to either change the node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel to use `componentDidUpdate`, use another component for carousel or disable the warning until the carousel maintainers updates their package.

To disable it you can do, inside you App.js, in the constructor:

```
import {YellowBox} from 'react-native'; //import it 


YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: componentWillReceiveProps']);
```

Hope this helps you!

EDIT.

About the other Warning you've got. That happens when you do a `setState` when a component has already been unmounted. Make sure that recreates that scenario. I would suggest to not ignore this warning using YellowBox but solve it.

Comment: Perfect Thanks very much

Comment: what about the error of can't perform react state update on unmounted component ? how to fix it ?